# How to increase the icon size in .chm file?

Tags: c#, chm

I am creating the help document in HTML Help Workshop. For higher resolution I am increasing the content font size (Change project option->Font->Change). But the icons have the same size. Image is attached here:
[Chm icon size issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfEAa.png)

Is there way to change the icon size and expander size?

Comment: Those icons are part of the application itself. You can't change them, at least not from your chm file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, no.

I do not recommend experimenting here. Also the very limited use of custom icons is limited in height and width to 16px.

Unfortunately this feature was never fully completed by Microsoft.

BTW - you didn't say anything about this in your question, but I think it's also about high-resolution monitors.

There is a very well written tutorial [How to get .CHM files to work on ultra-high resolution monitors](https://www.helpandmanual.com/downloads_delphi.html#chm4k)

[ZIP file link](https://www.helpandmanual.com/download/getting-html-help-ready-for-4k-monitors.zip)

In this tutorial, you learn what to take care of in HTML Help on 4K monitors, what to avoid, and how to get things right!